# Cloud Logging doesn't work on a Container-optimized OS running a container

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-container-optimized-os

I'm running a Docker container on a GCE instance under the Container-optimizes OS. I've followed this manual https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/logging and added the `google-logging-enabled` metadata value to enable sending containers' logs to Cloud Logging:

[instance metadata screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyIGy.png)

But it doesn't work. I can't see containers' logs in the Cloud Logging:

[cloud logging screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM9lh.png)

While I have a lot of container logs in reality:

[container logs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBACH.png)

How to make it working and really send containers' logs to Cloud Logging?

**Update**
The log filter is the default one: `(resource.type="gce_instance" AND resource.labels.instance_id="***") OR (resource.type="global" AND jsonPayload.instance.id="***")` that means that all types of logs from the current instance should be shown.

Comment: Use this filter "resource.type="gce_instance" AND resource.labels.instance_id="xxxxxxxxx" AND logName=projects/xxxxxxxxxx/logs/cos_containers"

Comment: COS has a low logging level set. This means logs at a higher level will not be sent to Stackdriver. I did some research on this but never found a permanent solution to change the log level. I think only ERROR and WARN are passed up to Stackdriver. My answer on this post has details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65768214/8016720

Comment: @John Hanley, What's the relation between Cloud Logging and Stackdriver? As far as I understood they are two different services?

Comment: Stackdriver is the old name for `Operations: Cloud Logging`. I still use the term Stackdriver out of habit. One of my favorite services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was that my service account associated with the instance had no the `Logs Writer` permission. I found that by running the `sudo systemctl status stackdriver-logging` command which shown the following:

```
● stackdriver-logging.service - Fluentd container for Stackdriver Logging
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/stackdriver-logging.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-03-05 01:18:55 UTC; 1h 12min ago
 Main PID: 385 (docker)
    Tasks: 9 (limit: 2382)
   Memory: 31.9M
      CPU: 751ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/stackdriver-logging.service
           └─385 /usr/bin/docker run --rm --name=stackdriver-logging-agent -v /etc/stackdriver/logging.config.d/:/etc/google-fluentd/config.d/ -v /var/log:/var/log -v /var/lib/docker/containers/:/v

Mar 05 02:30:11 jwp-gitlab-runner-m3l0 docker[385]: 2021-03-05 02:30:11 +0000 [warn]: #0 Dropping 1 log message(s) error="User unauthorized to access *** for resource ***
```

By googling the error message I found the answer in the GitHub issue https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluent-plugin-google-cloud/issues/295

The following answer also helped me to diagnose the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65768214/8016720

Now I have all the logs I want in Cloud Logging.

Comment: The answer link in my comment included steps to diagnose this problem.

Comment: Yup, you also mentioned this role name. But I somehow missed it while reading...